# Appium AWS devicefarm

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'android'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see. when i run in aws devicefarm we are unable to run appliacation can you please give any solution?

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'android'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see.